# Delete multiple files from multiple branch using bfg repo cleaner

Tags: bfg-repo-cleaner

I want to delete multiple files from multiple branches using bfg repo cleaner. Can anyone please suggest way how to do that. I am able to delete single file from single branch using the command `bfg --delete-files filename my-repo.git`.Please provide steps how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The '--delete-files' parameter works with naming patterns. For example, if you want to remove all cerificate files, of type '.pem', the following line will work:

```
bfg --delete-files '*.pem' my-repo.git
```