# Delete list of files with BFG-repo-cleaner

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

We are trying to shrink our git repository to under 500MB due to deployment issues.

To achieve that, we have created a new branch where we have moved all old images, videos and fonts to AWS S3.

I can easily get the list of files with `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master -- public/assets/`.

Now, I have tried to run [BFG-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) 1.14.0 on each file. But I have 400 files and it is taking ages to delete each files separately (still running as I'm writing this).

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master -- public/assets/ | xargs -i basename '{}' | xargs -i bfg --delete-files '{}'`

Since each file is distinct, I can not really use a glob pattern, as suggested at [Delete multiple files from multiple branch using bfg repo cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072057/delete-multiple-files-from-multiple-branch-using-bfg-repo-cleaner).

I tried to separate each file with a comma but that resulted in [BFG-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) telling me:

> BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??

**Is there a way to provide multiple files to [BFG-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) without a glob pattern?**

PS. The command I tried with multiple files is: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D master -- public/assets/ | xargs -i basename '{}' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' | xargs -i bfg --delete-files '{}' && git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

PPS. The `bfg` command is on my PATH as a simple bash script with `java -jar /tools/BFG-repo-cleaner/bfg-1.14.0.jar "$@"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I have 400 files and it is taking ages to delete each files separately

That is why the tool to use (python-based) is [`newren/git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (see [installation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md))

That way, you can feed that tool a file, with the list of files in it:

```
git filter-repo --paths-from-file <filename> --invert-paths
```

From [the documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_filtering_based_on_many_paths):

> Similarly, you could use `--paths-from-file` to delete many files.
>
> For example, you could run `git filter-repo --analyze` to get reports, look in one such as `.git/filter-repo/analysis/path-deleted-sizes.txt` and copy all the filenames into a file such as `/tmp/files-i-dont-want-anymore.txt`, and then run:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --invert-paths \
>                 --paths-from-file /tmp/files-i-dont-want-anymore.txt
> ```
>
> to delete them all.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! Looks like a much better tool. However, I get an error from a fresh `git clone` (possibly due to switching from main branch) that I don't understand. > Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected at most one entry in the reflog for HEAD)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Make sure your `git status` is clean before launching that command.

Comment: Our `.git` directory shrank from 454MB to 338MB after using  `git filter-repo`, `git reflog expire` and `git gc`. :) Does `git filter-repo` also takes care of other branches and tags?

Comment: Nice! I see that `git filter-repo` also fixed our branches. And it is super fast!

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Well done. It can operate on all branches.